# Is ServiceStack v4 beta ready for Mono?

Tags: mono, servicestack

After converting my solution to SS v4 from v3 - in VS 2012 on Windows 8 I hit the 10 services limit otherwise seems to work. However on OS X, in Xamarin Studio with Mono 3.2.5 I get a stackoverflow exception.

In the stack trace every line is:

at System.Attribute.GetHashCode () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.5/mcs/class/corlib/System/Attribute.cs:261

Any ideas what causes that? When I switch back to my v3 branch it still works fine.

Before I get a paid license I'm interested in how much testing SS v4 received on Mono. Is it just as compatible as v3? I was hoping for it to be better with the Razor improvements.

Comment: You can see in the source here, that an attribute on an attribute would probably cause a StackOverflow exception:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Attribute.cs  

`public override int GetHashCode ()
{
    int result = GetType ().GetHashCode ();
    …
}`

Comment: Checking Mono source suggests this is a bug that's been fixed after 3.2.5. (Although just glancing at the code, looks like the fix would cause an overflow exception...)

Comment: Sorry no, v4 on Mono hasn't been properly tested. We'll look at testing it properly in the next couple months during the beta.

Comment: Ah man - just stumbled accross the exact same issue... was hoping to use my macbook as my primary dev box and ditch all windows boxes - this is the only thing holding me back!

Comment: The reason that this Mono bug is triggered, is that ServiceStack's AttributeBase overrides ```TypeId```, returning ```this```. @mythz , will we just have to wait until Mono 3.2.5 goes stable, or would you consider either overriding GetHashCode() in AttributeBase, or using a GUID as TypeID?

Comment: Actually, the bug fix doesn't seem to be included in Mono 3.2.5 either, so if ServiceStack is to work on Mono, AttributeBase needs to be changed...

Comment: @dabide so just return a new Guid for Mono?

Comment: @mythz, yes, creating a new Guid for each instance, and use that as TypeId would work (like the example in the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.typeid(v=vs.110).aspx). Just out of curiosity, why do you return ```this```?

Comment: @dabide it's required if you want to add multiple attributes via the TypeDescriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes beta is ready!

Check the new Pcl release!

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes

Thx @mythz