# If possible, would updating to Mono 3.2.6 fix this?

Tags: mono

I am running into the same problem spoken about here:

[Is ServiceStack v4 beta ready for Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487596/is-servicestack-v4-beta-ready-for-mono)

To be clear - I am getting  StackOverflowException :

```
at System.Attribute.GetHashCode () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.5/mcs/class/corlib/System/Attribute.cs:261
```

Would upgrading Mono fix this? And if so, where can I get a pre-release version of Mono from? the downloads page only shows me latest released versions

Comment: there's no other way to answer this than to test it

Comment: @knocte that's fair enough but there was a second part ot the question :) "And if so, where can I get a pre-release version of Mono from?"

Comment: those are two very different questions, which you should ask separately

Answer (score 0):

Just try it out. You can find all public releases of Mono here:

http://download.mono-project.com/archive/

For newer versions, you will have to build it yourself from the code at:

https://github.com/mono/mono/